# Tundish Lift Lower mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I have two no of motors connected in parallel of 7.5 kw max current capacity 30Amps.
The load is about 18Ton is the motor sufficient to lift this load.
The mechanical arrangement of screw jack system.

The current now taken by motor is as such,
Up movement: 37amps initial current and normal 33Amps.
Down movemenf: 20amps initial current and normal 18amps.

Comment: Archimedes said give me a long enough lever and a fulcrum and I will move the world - so what gearing are you considering?

Comment: It will depend on the mechanical advantage of the jack screw or gearing.